# Set User context in Email Template

Tags: apex, email, chatter, email-template, collaborationgroup

I would know if it's possible set a "User" for an email template.

In a my email template I use `{!User.Name}`.
I have a class and a trigger on CollaborationGroupMember and I send an email each time that a user is added in a chatter group:

## Class

```
public with sharing class ClassToSendMail {

    public static void sendMail(String emailTemplate, String mailRecipient, Id targetObjectID) {

        Id templateId; 
        templateId = [select id, name from EmailTemplate where developername = : emailTemplate].id;

        OrgWideEmailAddress owa = [select id, Address, DisplayName from OrgWideEmailAddress limit 1];

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toRecipients = new String[]{'testMail@domain.com'};

        email.setToAddresses(toRecipients);
        email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owa.id);
        email.setTargetObjectId(targetObjectID);
        email.setTemplateId(templateId);    
        email.setSaveAsActivity(false);

        try 
        {
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
        }
        catch (EmailException e) {String errorMsg='Error in : '+e.getMessage();}
    }
}
```

## Trigger

```
trigger TriggerSendMail on CollaborationGroupMember (after insert) {
    for(CollaborationGroupMember newMember : Trigger.new){
        System.debug('@@@ newMember: ' + newMember);
        User userToSendMail = [SELECT id, Email FROM User WHERE ID=:newMember.MemberID];
        ClassToSendMail.sendMail('UserAddedGroup', userToSendMail.Email , userToSendMail.Id);
    }
}
```

When I add an user in a chatter group, `{!User.Name}` is replace with name of the current user logged in org and not the user set as targetObject.

Comment: When you say current user it means the logged in user( the user in which this email will be send means the sender)?

Comment: Did you try `{!Receiving_User.Name}` instead of `{!User.Name}`?

Comment: @TusharSharma yes, "current user" means user logged in org.

Comment: @MartinLezerno, I don't try {!Receiving_User.Name} but now I replace {!User.Name} with {!Contact.Name} and as targetObject I set Contact related to User and not User, and now it's ok.     I don't understand why with User object not allow replace instead with Contact it works

Comment: Glad your solution is working. It can't work with the User variable because it's related to the current user in the context. The one that triggered the send.

Comment: Good to know you got the solution. You can post it as answer.